# Don't know why the array out of bounds exception occurs

Tags: java, arrays

This is the question i tried to solve:
Save the string “WELCOMETOZOHOCORPORATION” in a two dimensional array and search for substring like “too” in the two dimensional string both from left to right and from top to bottom.

W   E   L   C   O/n
M   E   T   O   Z/n
O   H   O   C   O/n 
R   P   O   R   A/n
T   I   O   N
Here the /n is used to indicate the nextline
And print the start and ending index as

Start index : <1,2>

End index: <3, 2>
But i don't know why the error is occurring.!

```
public class Try1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        String str=sc.next();
        char arr[][]=new char[5][5];
        char a[]=str.toCharArray();
        int l=a.length;
        int k=0,flag=0;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                if(k!=l){
                arr[i][j]=a[k];
                k++;}else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the string to search");
        String str1=sc.next();
        char b[]=str1.toCharArray();
        int l1=b.length,y=0,count=0,rl=0,td=0,v=l1-1;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                if(arr[i][j]==b[y])//THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
                {
                    count++;
                    for(y=1;y<l1;y++){
                        if(arr[i][j+y]==b[y]){
                            rl=count+rl;
                            if(rl==l1){
                                flag=1;
                                System.out.println("Start Index: "+i+","+j);
                                System.out.println("End Index: "+i+","+(j+v));
                                break;
                            }
                        }else if(arr[i+y][j]==b[y]){
                            td=count+td;
                            if(td==l1){
                                flag=1;
                                System.out.println("Start Index: "+i+","+j);
                                System.out.println("End Index: "+(i+v)+","+j);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(flag==0){
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
The error i am facing is,
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at try1.Try1.main(Try1.java:48)
Could you help me guys.
```

Comment: Neither did I understand your requirements nor the problems you have. Please try to clarify.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, Hope you may understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because the maximum index in the array, `b` for the string `TOO` is `2` while you are trying to access an element beyond the index `2`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the string: ");
        String str = sc.next();
        char arr[][] = new char[5][5];
        char a[] = str.toCharArray();
        int l = a.length;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (k != l) {
                    arr[i][j] = a[k];
                    k++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter the string to search: ");
        String str1 = sc.next();
        char b[] = str1.toCharArray();
        int i, j, countH = 0, countV = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            countH = countV = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < 5 && countH < b.length && countV < b.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j] == b[countH]) {
                    countH++;
                } else if (arr[j][i] == b[countV]) {
                    countV++;
                }
            }
            if (countH == b.length) {
                found = true;
                System.out.println("Found horizontally starting at index " + "[" + (i) + "][" + (j - b.length) + "]");
            }
            if (countV == b.length) {
                found = true;
                System.out.println("Found vertically starting at index " + "[" + (j - b.length) + "][" + i + "]");
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the string: WELCOMETOZOHOCORPORATION
W  E  L  C  O  
M  E  T  O  Z  
O  H  O  C  O  
R  P  O  R  A  
T  I  O  N    
Enter the string to search: TOO
Found vertically starting at index [1][2]
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the string: WELCOMETOZOHOCORPORATION
W  E  L  C  O  
M  E  T  O  Z  
O  H  O  C  O  
R  P  O  R  A  
T  I  O  N   
Enter the string to search: ABC
Not Found
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the string: WELCOMETOZOHOCORPORATION
W  E  L  C  O  
M  E  T  O  Z  
O  H  O  C  O  
R  P  O  R  A  
T  I  O  N    
Enter the string to search: ZOA
Found vertically starting at index [1][4]
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the string: WELCOMETOZOHOCORPORATION
W  E  L  C  O  
M  E  T  O  Z  
O  H  O  C  O  
R  P  O  R  A  
T  I  O  N    
Enter the string to search: MET
Found horizontally starting at index [1][0]
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the string: WELCOMETOZOHOCORPORATION
W  E  L  C  O  
M  E  T  O  Z  
O  H  O  C  O  
R  P  O  R  A  
T  I  O  N    
Enter the string to search: PORA
Found horizontally starting at index [3][1]
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the string: WELCOMETOZOHOCORPORATION
W  E  L  C  O  
M  E  T  O  Z  
O  H  O  C  O  
R  P  O  R  A  
T  I  O  N    
Enter the string to search: PORB
Not Found
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it gives wrong index values for other outputs bro.@Arvind Kumar Avinash

Comment: @Cheeku - Everything was correct except a minor problem in displaying the index of search term when it is found horizontally. I have fixed it now and I hope, it meets your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any other issue you come across.

Comment: sorry bro ,i think that there might be a problem in your code, could you check for "porb" as input it is printing index value for a string which is not present ,@Arvind Kumar Avinash

Comment: It was because I thought that you wanted to enter a search text of only `3` characters and therefore I had hardcoded `3`. I've replaced `3` with `b.length` and now it is working for the search text `PORA` or `PORB` as expected. Feel free to comment in case of any other issue.

Comment: Tq bro for your continuous support bro,@Arvind Kumar Avinash

Comment: @Cheeku - You are most welcome. I wish you success!

Answer (score 3):

```
                if(arr[i][j]==b[y])//THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
```

The problem is with `b[y]`. The first time through the loop `y` is 0, no problem. A few lines later in an inner loop you do

```
                    for(y=1;y<l1;y++){
```

This loop leaves `y` equal to `l1`, the length of the word searched for (3 in the case of `TOO`). So the second time you get to the line where the error occurs, `y` is 3 in the example, and you are trying to compare to the element at index 3 in an array of length 3. This causes the exception (as you know, array indices are 0-based, so the valid indices in the array are 0, 1, and 2).

I haven’t understood how your code was supposed to work, so hesitate to suggest a fix. If appropriate, you may set `y` back to 0 for each iteration of the outer loop.